# Unix permissions from Windows

Tags: windows, linux, unix, permissions

I have a D-Link DNS-323 NAS, running some sort of Linux as its OS.
I map a volume as a share in Windows Vista (Ultimate SP2). There are some directories and files on that share that I cannot change/delete - no matter what I try. Trying all of Windows security/permissions dialogs don't work, as the files owner is "Unix/root" and all other Windows users have read-only permissions.

I managed to ssh into the OS and verified that these files belong to 'root' - the user under which I log in, and all the other files (the ones I can change) belong to 'nobody'.

All fine and well, while I'm in ssh, I can always "chmod +w" the files, or "chown nobody". But my question is this: how can I make my Windows user (let's call him 'admin') impersonate 'root' on the Linux, so I can simply manipulate files from Windows, without resorting to ssh?

In other words, and to make the whole question plainer: how do you tell your OS that a certain user on Windows is a certain user on linux? (that way, I can have 'admin' be 'root').

Thanks in advance,
Guy

Comment: This seems like might belong on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the NAS is running samba (almost certainly), there should be a samba config file somewhere in /etc.  But I don't know if it would be editable.

The remapping between windows/Linux and permissions is all done on the server (samba) side.
There are a lot of Samba faqs about this.

Comment: Thanks! Samba was the keyword I needed. With it, I found a link to the answer (I hope - haven't tried yet): http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/samba-permissions-with-d-link-dns-323-636229/

Answer (score 4):

[Samba](http://www.samba.org/samba/what_is_samba.html) can do something like you've said.  it basically emulates windows compatible permissions on a linux box..

Answer (score -1):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) can do that.

EDIT:

The [cacls](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true) command in Windows looks like it does what you want.

Comment: I realize I can use a myriad of Linux-like tools and terminals - but how can I do it from Windows natively? Thanks.

Comment: CACLS is simply the command line version of the Windows permissions dialog - how can it help? Don't I need a domain user in order to use it?